# Java. Scanner Trying to to a loop until user quits

Tags: java

I've been trying to make a while loop where I enter in a movie number until the user types 'q' for quit, but every time I enter a valid number, I have to enter it twice before it prompts me with the "Enter movie number" message again. And the break function doesn't work when I wish to leave the loop. I simply wish to enter in the movie number once and break out when I want to.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter in movie number: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            if(!input.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.println("invalid input");
                continue;
            }

            if (Integer.parseInt(input.next()) < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("invalid no negative numbers");
                continue;
            }
            if(Objects.equals(input.next(), "q"))
                break;
        }
        

    }
```

I tried other variations of the while loop, but a similar thing has happened.

Comment: You're trying to be too clever. Get the input first and save it to a variable. *Then* test what the variable holds and react to this.

Comment: Not directly to your question, but don't name your `Scanner` `input` and don't recreate it on every loop iteration.

Comment: Ah! thank you. Sorry for the trivial questions I tend to overthink too much.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your intention is to get one line of input, and if it is a number, process it somehow, and if not check if the user wants to quit.

You've got a couple problems with your program, firstly, you're creating a new `Scanner` within the while loop, which creates unnecessary overhead. Second, you're trying to get 2 lines of input within your loop, you wait for the user to input an integer, then you try to parse that integer with `input.next()`. Afterwards, you call `input.next()` again to check if the user wants to quit. By calling `next()` twice, you're requiring the user to input 2 lines, causing the issue you were describing.

You can fix this by calling `next()` once and storing its return value in a variable, then check if it equals q for quit, otherwise you can parse an integer value from it.

Here is working code that applies fixes to these issues:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter in a movie number:");
            // Get user input
            String input = scanner.next();

            // If the input equals q, we break out of the loop
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) break;
            
            int intInput;
            try {
                // Get integer input
                intInput = Integer.parseInt(input);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) { // Input was not a number
                System.out.println("Invalid, must input a number");
                continue;
            }
            
            if(intInput < 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid, no negative numbers");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, a small note, instead of using `Object.equals` to check if two strings are equal you can just use the equals method inside of the `String` class like so: `str1.equals(str2)`.